# How to create a non-editable website using JavaScript and Html

Tags: javascript, html, web-deployment

All of the websites I have seen can be edited using this function in the console of Inspect element window. I want to disable this operation. I am building a result sheet of an exam and I dont want others to edit (even locally and make it look realistic)

```
document.body.contentEditable=true
```

If this boolean is changed to true anyone can edit the website. So how to make sure that doesnot happen

Comment: By default `contentEditable`is not true. Remove the line or set it to false. However, by using the console (=Devtool) most websites can be manipulated, yet that is just the local client view and not the actual website on the server. The only way I can think of is using Flash/Applets/something alike.

Comment: I know its false in default. But anyone can change it to true. I dont want anyone to be able to that

Comment: That property does not do what you want/expect it to do.

Comment: Thanks @Lain but being a result sheet I dont want them to edit in local system even. I dont want realistic fake screenshots.

Comment: Ultimately you can not disable the posibility to fake screenshots, no matter what you do. Even if you output it in another format (pdf/png). Yet, why do those fakes bother you? Such change nothing about the actual result.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the time. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really prevent people from modifying your website locally. Try looking for other solutions.